# Firefox Addon Button Code Not Working - Javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox, button, navbar

I am creating a Firefox extension that is designed to place a button automatically on the toolbar that, when clicked, will open a web page in a new tab. I have used the code snippets from the Mozilla dev site but, when both are put together, only the button placement works. The button does nothing when clicked.

I don't know too much about javascript, so I have no idea what is going wrong here. The entire extension has passed all Mozilla validation checks with no errors and no warnings.

Here is the code. Any help you could offer would be greatly appreciated.

```
CustomButton = {
1: function installButton(toolbarId, id, afterId) {
    if (!document.getElementById(id)) {
        var toolbar = document.getElementById(toolbarId);

        // If no afterId is given, then append the item to the toolbar
        var before = null;
        if (afterId) {
            let elem = document.getElementById(afterId);
            if (elem && elem.parentNode == toolbar)
                before = elem.nextElementSibling;
        }

        toolbar.insertItem(id, before);
        toolbar.setAttribute("currentset", toolbar.currentSet);
        document.persist(toolbar.id, "currentset");
    }

if (firstRun) {
    installButton("nav-bar", "my-extension-navbar-button");
}
},

2: function () {

const url = "http://www.mysite.com/"

document
    .getElementById("content")

.webNavigation

.loadURI(url, 0, null, null, null)

}
}
```

I am not very sharp at this, which is why I am asking the question here instead of searching for other examples, which make no sense to me. If someone could show me how to modify this specific code to do what I need it to do, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

This will work from FF 29, which will be released on April 2014
It adds an action-Button to the toolbar, once you click it it will load the http://www.example.com site in a new tab; if you prefer to load a new window use require("sdk/windows") instead.

Using the addon-sdk

```
var ui = require("sdk/ui");
var action_button = ui.ActionButton({
    id: "my-button",
    label: "Open example page!",
    icon: "./icon.png",
    onClick: function() {
        require("sdk/tabs").open("http://www.example.com");
    }
});
```